# How to reset the datetimepicker

Tags: vb6

Using datetimepicker default min date and max date is

```
dtpicker1.mindate = cdate("01/01/2012")
dtpicker1.maxdate = cdate("31/01/2012")
```

I want to change the min date and max date in datetimepicker at run time.

Button1

i am passing the mindate and maxdate again like

```
dtpicker1.mindate = cdate("01/02/2012")
dtpicker1.maxdate = cdate("28/02/2012")
```

But it is showing error as "`A value was specified for the MinDate Property that is higher than current value of MaxDate.`"

How to solve this problem

Comment: Don't use date literals like that, they're ambiguous and will give different results in different locales. Use the `#mm/dd/yyyy#` format instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two way to do this:
**1)** If your default `MinDate` and `MaxDate` is always `'01/01/2012'` and `'31/01/2012'`
Then you need to define `MaxDate` before definding `MinDate` like this:

```
dtpicker1.maxdate = cdate("28/02/2012")
dtpicker1.mindate = cdate("01/02/2012")
```

**2)** If your default `MinDate` and `MaxDate` is changed every time then first set `MinDate` lower than your desired `MaxDate` and `MaxDate` higher than your desired `MinDate`
then you can set `MinDate` and `MaxDate` what you want like this:

```
dtpicker1.mindate = cdate("01/01/1988")
dtpicker1.maxdate = cdate("31/12/2030")
dtpicker1.mindate = cdate("01/02/2012")
dtpicker1.maxdate = cdate("28/02/2012")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change maxdate first. And check if dtpicker1 must be instead dtpicker2

```
dtpicker1.maxdate = cdate("28/02/2012")    
dtpicker1.mindate = cdate("01/02/2012")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it's a typing mistake in my question, i mentioned dtpicker2 instead of dtpicker1, now check my question plz..